# Filtered ObservableCollection does not update ListView on WPF UI

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, observablecollection

I am trying to filter a ObservableCollection databinded to a ListView on my WPF UI.  However, when the collection refreshes, the ListView becomes blank and doesn't show anything.  I am also trying to teach myself the MVVM pattern.  The issue is probably how I'm not refreshing the control, but how can I get it to refresh in the MVVM pattern?  I'm used to doing Winforms and code behinds, and the filter logic happens when the user clicks on the Search button - which calls the ApplicationModel.Search method.

Model code:

```
public class AppObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public AppObject(string name, string desc, string owner, string email)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Description = desc;
        this.Owner = owner;
        this.Email = email;
    }
}

public class ApplicationsModel : ObservableCollection<AppObject>
{
    private static object threadLocker;
    private static ApplicationsModel current;

    static ApplicationsModel()
    {
        threadLocker = new object();
    }

    public static ApplicationsModel Current
    {
        get
        {
            lock (threadLocker)
            {
                if (current == null)
                {
                    current = new ApplicationsModel();
                }
            }
            return current;
        }
    }

    private ApplicationsModel()
    {
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private ApplicationsModel(IEnumerable<AppObject> collection)
        : base(collection)
    {
    }

    private void Refresh()
    {
                    try
                    {
                            // Query database to get the initial data - this code works fine
                    }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string error = String.Format("Could not refresh repository list: {0}", e.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(error, "Error Refreshing", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }

    public void Search(string key)
    {
        IEnumerable<AppObject> newList = current.Items.Where<AppObject>(t => t.Name.Equals(key));
        foreach (AppObject app in newList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(app.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(app.Description);
        }
        current.Clear();
        current = null;
        current = new ApplicationsModel(newList);
    }

    public void ClearSearch()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClearSearch method called");
    }
}
```

ViewModel code:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<AppObject> AppCollection { get; set; }
    static string searchString;
    static string emailString;
    public AppObject SelectedApp { get; set; }
    public string AppToSearch
    {
        get
        {
            return searchString;
        }
        set
        {
            searchString = value;
        }
    }
    public string AppToRequest
    {
        get
        {
            return SelectedApp.Email;
        }
        set
        {
            SelectedApp.Email = value;
        }
    }
    private SearchButtonCommand searchButtonCmd;
    private ClearButtonCommand clearButtonCmd;
    private EmailButtonCommand emailButtonCmd;

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        this.AppCollection = ApplicationsModel.Current;
    }

    public ICommand SearchButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.searchButtonCmd == null)
            {
                this.searchButtonCmd = new SearchButtonCommand();
            }
            return this.searchButtonCmd;
        }
    }

    public ICommand ClearButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.clearButtonCmd == null)
            {
                this.clearButtonCmd = new ClearButtonCommand();
            }
            return this.clearButtonCmd;
        }
    }

    public ICommand EmailButtonPressed
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.emailButtonCmd == null)
            {
                this.emailButtonCmd = new EmailButtonCommand();
            }
            return this.emailButtonCmd;
        }
    }

    private class SearchButtonCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            string searchkey = ApplicationViewModel.searchString;
            ApplicationsModel.Current.Search(searchkey);
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class ClearButtonCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ApplicationsModel.Current.ClearSearch();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private class EmailButtonCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            string targetEmail = ApplicationViewModel.emailString;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

UI XAML:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:ApplicationViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Height="84" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,5,5" Name="imgNexusLogo" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="600" Source="C:\source\Nexus\NexusShop\Images\nexus1bannerlong.png" />
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Search for Application">
            <Label.Foreground>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="LightCyan" />
            </Label.Foreground>
        </Label>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Width="500" Text="{Binding AppToSearch}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Height="20" Margin="3" Background="LightCyan" Content="Search" vm:ButtonBehaviour.SearchCommand="{Binding SearchButtonPressed}" />
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Height="20" Margin="3" Background="LightCyan" Content="Clear Search" vm:ButtonBehaviour.ClearCommand="{Binding ClearButtonPressed}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ListView Grid.Row="2" BorderBrush="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AppCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedNexusApp}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application Description" Width="800" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Application Owner" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Owner}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="200" Height="30" Margin="3" Background="LightCyan" Content="Request Application" vm:ButtonBehaviour.EmailCommand="{Binding EmailButtonPressed}" />
</Grid>
```

Again, The functionality which filters occurs when the search button is clicked, and it runs the method on ApplicationModel.Search(string stringtofilteron).  I based my MVVM classes on this tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF

Thanks for your help!

Fixed code:
        public class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged

```
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion

ApplicationsModel.Current.Search(this.searchString);
NotifyPropertyChanged();
```

And I changed the Refresh method in my model to do the filtering there.

Comment: Jeffrey Khan is right - you are missing INotify.  Couple of questions.  1)  Why are you using the threadlocker?  All of this work is done on the UI thread and shouldn't be touched by other threads.  2)  Why are you creating a new view model every time you refresh?  Why don't you just refresh the Observable Collection on the View Model?  This is easier to do and is friendlier when dealing with events that may be wired up on the view model.  If you don't manually remove the event handlers - the view models are never disposed and your app will eat memory.

Comment: Yes, that was a clusterf**k and would result in memory leaks.  It was very late and I was tired, so that's why I wrote that kind of stuff.  I just changed the refresh method per your suggestion to take a parameter to filter on, then that works fine and doesn't create a new collection every time and we don't have to worry about disposal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewModel needs to Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and notify when `AppCollection` has been changed.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx

Comment: That did it!  For anyone looking through this as a guide, I have edited my post to reflect the changes which I did to get it to work

Comment: Your ViewModel isn't supposed to implement INPC, that's the model's job.  The link you provided doesn't say to do that in the VM either.